# What are skeletons capable of in minecraft pocket edition

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Ok so I was playing minecraft PE with my sister and a skeleton climbed up a ladder from the mines and basically trolled us. So now I am wondering what are the capabilities of skeletons in minecraft PE?

Comment: All monsters can climb ladders. It's not just skeletons.

Comment: I know, but that was the first time I've seen that.

Comment: If you knew that, why were you surprised enough to ask this?

Comment: Well gee I was crafting wool and it almost killed me

Answer (score 1):

[Skeletons](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Skeleton) can:

- use a bow to shoot you (with a range of 10m)
- navigate mazes to find you
- hide in shade to avoid burning
- make rattling noises

Like all hostile mobs, Skeletons can also:

- climb ladders if they bump into them (they will not path *to* ladders, but will use them if their pathing takes them to a ladder)
- know where you are even through walls, within 16m
- spawn on solid blocks where there is light level 7 or less
- ruin your day

Comment: This is an answer for PC, not Pocket Edition

Comment: @Timtech Skeletons are the same in both games.

Comment: In Pocket Edition, skeletons cannot wear armor.

Comment: @Timtech Yet. But true, so I'll pull that. Remind me to put it back in when PE catches up to that feature.

Comment: Okay, I will. But that'll probably be in a year or three.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the problems they can cause listed in SevenSidedDie's answer, they can also drop many useful items, such as feathers, arrows, and bones.

Bones can be turned into Bone Meal, which can instantly grow crops.